Unwanted margin in angular
I'm using angular, I want to create a header component, but when I add it to my main component, it appears with some margin.

<header id="actionVar">
    <app-home-icon id="homeicon"></app-home-icon>
    <app-carrito-componente id="carritoicon"></app-carrito-componente>
    <app-search-products id="busqueda"></app-search-products>
</header>

This is the head component, which in turn is composed of other components such as the home button
<header>
    <app-head-component></app-head-component>
</header>

here I add the head to the main component.

I'm new, if I'm doing something wrong or bad practices, please tell me

I tried setting margins, padding and border to 0 but nothing works. By setting the absolute position it leaves me, but from what I read your design will not be responsive

Did you investigate where the margin is coming from using browser's dev-tools ?

Like @Hujaakbar said you should try to use inspect-element dev tools to determine which element is giving the margin.
But to save you some time, more than likely it's the body that has a margin. If you add some css saying body { margin: 0; } you won't have the margin at that point.

This is not margin for the header or someother tag,its The body tag in most web browsers actually starts off with a default margin. This margin is typically set to 8 pixels on all sides (top, bottom, left, and right).
Solution :
body { margin: 0; }


It worked for me, thank you all very much.

If the answer is working for you, could you please mark the question as resolved by accepting the answer ?
